# Get only unique item from collection and sum other values to one item

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I do have this laravel collection

```
    Collection {#239 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => array:21 [▼
          "dueDate" => "2017-09-29"
          "groupByCode" => "REMINDER"
          "date" => "2017-09-29"
          "number" => "9030014"
          "status" => "Reminder"
          "currencyCode" => "kr"
          "amount" => 1745.0
          "remainingAmount" => 1745.0

        ],
  2 => array:21 [▼
          "dueDate" => "2017-09-29"
          "groupByCode" => "REMINDER"
          "date" => "2017-09-29"
          "number" => "9030014"
          "status" => "Reminder"
          "currencyCode" => "kr"
          "amount" => 1345.0
          "remainingAmount" => 1745.0

        ],
        3 => array:21 [▼
          "dueDate" => "2017-09-29"
          "groupByCode" => "INVOICE"
          "date" => "2017-09-29"
          "number" => "9030026"
          "status" => "invoice"
          "currencyCode" => "kr"
          "amount" => 2389.0
          "remainingAmount" => 2389.0

        ]
      ]
    }
```

Now my question is how to get only unique items based on status, example above I have two items with status Reminder, instead I want to keep the same collection format but in return to have only one item with status 'Reminder' with all existing keys and the sum will be sum of both reminders....

I have tried to use `where('status', ''Reminder')->first() but does not work since it takes only firts element.

So the output should be something along the lines of this:

```
    Collection {#239 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => array:21 [▼
          "dueDate" => "2017-09-29"
          "groupByCode" => "REMINDER"
          "date" => "2017-09-29"
          "number" => "9030014"
          "status" => "Reminder"
          "currencyCode" => "kr"
          "amount" => TOTAL OF BOTH REMINDERS
          "remainingAmount" => 1745.0

        ],
  2 => array:21 [▼
          "dueDate" => "2017-09-29"
          "groupByCode" => "INVOICE"
          "date" => "2017-09-29"
          "number" => "9030014"
          "status" => "Invoice"
          "currencyCode" => "kr"
          "amount" => 2312 
          "remainingAmount" => 1745.0

            ],
}
```

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
$invoices = $this->boatService->getInvoices(cleanSsn(session('ssn')));

$invoices = collect($invoices)->whereIn('status', ['Reminder', 'Invoice']);
```

Comment: share your try also ?

Comment: @user2486 ok check again

Answer (score 1):

You can make a raw query to sum the items and group them by status. Try this:

```
$collection = \DB::table('invoices')
                 ->select(\DB::raw('sum(amount) as amount_total, status'))
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: I just thought about `groupBy('groupByCode')` or ``groupBy('status')``

Comment: this is comming from an api service

Comment: Just little correction , may be he need to sum not count